# May one lie about knowing the difference between Haman and Mordechai on Purim?

Tags: halacha, purim, sheker-false, intoxication

If, on Purim, "Reuvein" asks "Shimon" if the latter knows the difference between Haman and Mordechai may Shimon lie and answer 'No'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes! According to the Maharsha in his chiddushei aggadot on talmud bava metzia (s.v. b'puryah). CF Titen Emes L’Yaakov page 52:26. Moadim V’zemanim (Rav Moshe Shternbuch shlitah) 6:109 who explains this opinion.

Comment: Why would he be allowed to lie?

Comment: @DoubleAA that is an interesting question which is worth asking. Ayin the sources I quote for more information.

Comment: That question is _this_ question. Including your reasoning will improve the value of your answer.

Comment: If indeed we follow the Maharsha's explanation of the Gemara, does that mean to the exclusion of all of the other rishonim who explain that gemara to be referring to something else entirely? If so it's hard to imagine why we should pasken like that. (On the other hand, even without the Maharsha the answer may still be yes, as otherwise "Reuvain" might pressure or argue "Shimon" into drinking more, which could cause a fight or 'perikas ol', as R' Moshe Shternbach mentions.)

Comment: @DoubleAA I disagree. A question such as may one cook milk and meat together if very different from the theological question of why the torah proscribes it.